# Arial Black - Websafe Font?

Tags: fonts

Is Arial Black web safe?

I have read it is but when I put it in my font declaration, I am being given Times New Roman back.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think it's available only on Windows. If you want to use it everywhere you can embed it as web font (@font-face). Here is a generator http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Does the licensing allow for the font to be embedded?

Comment: as @17bc17 write you need to know that. If license don't allow that you can find some free font that look similar and then embed it instead.

Comment: Can you show us your, font delclaration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to Code Style Font Survey (actually the best estimate you can have) Arial Black is commonly installed on about 97% of Windows and Mac computers and 68% of Linux machines. So, it's fairly safe to use it, but you got to provide substitutes for it in your font stack. Something like:

```
.my-style { font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', Gadget, sans-serif;
```

If you wish it to appear, even when it's not really installed on your (or any user) system, then you'll have to embed the font file by using @font-face directive in your CSS.

Here's Code Style Survey: http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-CombinedResultsFull.shtml

Comment: The link appears to be dead, is the answer still valid today? How about ios / Android devices?

Comment: @Luciano http://www.cssfontstack.com/ has info in Windows and Mac. Best  I can find for mobile  is this massive table http://blog.typekit.com/2013/04/17/fallback-fonts-on-mobile-devices/ but it doesn't include Android browsers, only iOS and Android system fonts

Answer (score 10):

I dont know how you declared your font. Normally, it should not happen the way you are saying it did.

Make sure you are declaring the font in this way

```
font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
```

Here are some other common patterns on web safe fonts, for you to choose from.

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Bookman Old Style', serif;
font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive;
font-family: Courier, monospace;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
font-family: Garamond, serif;
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
font-family: 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: 'MS Serif', 'New York', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
font-family: Symbol, sans-serif;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-family: Webdings, sans-serif;
font-family: Wingdings, 'Zapf Dingbats', sans-serif;
```

[Source](http://www.fonttester.com/help/list_of_web_safe_fonts.html)

Comment: "This page provided to the domain owner free by Sedo's Domain Parking" Seems like domain was bought by someone. Is there another list somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is no longer supported by Firefox (bug).

See http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/796630

Or https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644385

Some hacks have been proposed here to make it work:
[Is there a trick to show Arial Black in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861519/is-there-a-trick-to-show-arial-black-in-firefox)

Comment: It's also absent in safari iOS. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202771  Is it still worth considering it web-safe?

Comment: If you look for a good alternative to `'Arial Black'` **on IOS** try `'Arial-BoldMT'`.

Answer (score 2):

Set your font-weight to 900, followed by your font-family

```
{font-weight: 900; font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', Gadget, sans-serif;}
```

Works great for me.

Comment: This one solved my issue, now its really "bold" on mobile devices too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is web-safe, yes.

Have you tried using speech marks?

'Arial Black'

Comment: Yes ... still nothing ... silly question but could it be because the font is not installed on my computer?

Comment: That would be one reason yes! It should be on your system however, unless it has been deleted. If you use this kind of syntax;

body{font-family:"Arial Black", "Times New Roman", serif}

then the second (in this case "Times New Roman") will be used if the first font isn't available.

Comment: Arial Black should be on Windows and Mac systems, it might not be standard on other platforms